# View and table function in select query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In below create view statement I don't understand the how the phone_number is passed to a function `fn_services` (which considered as a table) and that function will return what kind of output a table or what?

Inside the function fn_service a variable

```
vServTab      services_tab := services_tab ();
```

is returned.

I don't understand this join...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW (COLA,COLB)
AS
SELECT COL1,COL2
FROM v_service_view spn,
TABLE (fn_services (spn.phone_number, NULL)) serv;
```

Comment: Please post the ddl of vservtab and fn_services

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The function `fn_services` must have at least two parameters, the first of which you are passing in the phone_number from each row in the spn table, the second of which you're passing in as null. The function then returns a set of results as a table (you should be able to tell that from the RETURN clause in the function's header). So, if you have two rows in your spn table/view, the first of which has a phone number that returns a table of 4 rows from the function and the second returns 6 rows, you'll end up with a result set of 10 rows from your query.